# Cannot find symbol constructor Scanner(java.lang.String[]) error?

Tags: java

The main aim of this this program is to be able to read a request line from a browser and to print out the first two words of that specific request line. However when it comes to compiling the program i am getting the same error again and again and i am not sure what the issue is. Here is the sample of the code that i wrote:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class UselessHTTPServer05 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(port);

        while (true) {
            Socket conn = serverSock.accept();
            Scanner scanin = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());
            String line = null;
            int nlines=0;
            String[] stringArray = new String[32];    

            while (true) {
                line = scanin.nextLine();
                if (line.length() == 0)
                    break;
                stringArray [nlines] = line;
                nlines = nlines + 1;
                //System.out.println("line "+nlines+": " + line);

                for (int i = 0; i < nlines; i++)
                    System.out.println("Line: " + i + " " + stringArray[i]);  

                Scanner scans = new Scanner(stringArray); 
                String command = scans.next();
                String resource = scans.next();
                System.out.println("Command: " + command);
                System.out.println("Resource " + resource);
            }

            String reply="HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n" +
               "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" +
               "\r\n" +
               "<h1>Sorry, work in progress</h1>\r\n";

            OutputStream outs = conn.getOutputStream();
            outs.write(reply.getBytes());
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The error is in regards to the Scanner part of the code where I have declared a Scanner called "Scans" and have written the code to carry out the task of scanning through the request line and prining out the first two words stored in "command" and "resource".

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: You might want to use `while (scanin.hasNextLine())` instead of the second `while (true)`.

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cd Desktop
    ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ javac UselessHTTPServer05.java
    UselessHTTPServer05 .java:30: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : constructor Scanner(java.lang.String[])
    location: class java.util.Scanner
    Scanner scans = new Scanner(stringArray); 
                    ^
1 error

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] stringArray = new String[32]; 
...
Scanner scans = new Scanner(stringArray);
```

`stringArray` is of type `String[]`, visit the [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) API to verify there's no such  constructor available.

Comment: Hmm, I have checked the Scanner API but I am unsure of what the constructor should consist of :s

Comment: I don't think you need a `Scanner` object here.. Simply loop on the array.

Answer (score 0):

as you can see on the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) site. there is no Constructor for String[]. You need to do it a different way, for example,

write your own scanner class where you write your own constructor of scanner and extend it with the Scanner class.

Or you change your String array to a other type (maybe Inputstream)

third way: you could do it, i don't know if this works in java or just in C, you could make an array out of scanners where you call the constructor for each string in the string array

```
PseudoCode

foreach String in StringArray
  ArrayofScanners[i] = new Scanner(String);
  i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution! I have created a String variable to store the first request line from the server. I also delclared a new Scanner to read through the request line, exaple is shown below:

```
String string = stringArray[0] //this will read the first request line
Scanner scans = new Scanner(string) //this will scan through the request line stored in string
```

The next step is to store the first two words of the request line into two String variables called Command and Resource:

```
String Command = scans.next();
String Resource = scans.next();
```

Finally, simply print out the two words:

```
System.out.println("Command: " + Command);
System.out.println("Resource: " + Resource);
```

Before the above code is implented here is what the request line consists of:

```
Line: 0 GET /file.html HTTP/1.1
```

After implementing the above code, the first two words are printed and stored into Command and Resource:

```
Command: GET
Resource: /file.html
```

Thank you for all those that replied to the post, really helped a lot!